# Convertir txt a arreglo python

Tags: python

estoy intentando hacer un monitor de redes locales pero cuando importo el arp -a a txt no puedo usarlo ni convertirlo en un arreglo

esto es lo que aparece cuando lo importo al archivo txt

```
Interface: 192.168.0.1 --- 0xe
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.56.255        ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static   

Interface: 192.168.1.1 --- 0x10
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.1.1           ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     dynamic
```

el codigo que utilizo

```
import os
from socket import gethostbyname, gethostname, gethostbyaddr

def main():
    
    host = gethostbyname(gethostname())
    os.system('arp -a > temp.txt')
    
    with open('temp.txt', 'r') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            line = line.split()[:2]
            if line and line[0].startswith(host[:4]) and(not line[0].endswith('255')):
                print(' , '.join(line) + " , ")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

intento meter las ip y las mac para poder usarlas para otra cosa

Comment: Existe la biblioteca [scapy](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) que te puede ser útil.

Comment: candid moe, no puedo usar scapy pide programas externos que no tengo instalados en la pc que necesito hacerlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No mencionas qué formato de salida estás buscando. Como eso devuelve una serie de IPs relacionadas a una interface de red, supuse que podía ser un diccionario donde la llave es la dirección de la interface y los valores, las otras IPs con sus MAC.

Coloqué más datos de ejemplo (las MAC no son reales):

```
Interfaz: 10.0.1.128 --- 0x4
  Dirección de Internet          Dirección física      Tipo
  10.0.1.1              70-a8-57-ed-c3-c8     dinámico  
  10.0.1.102            40-6d-64-f7-dc-ee     dinámico  
  10.0.1.147            80-68-95-77-06-07     dinámico  

Interfaz: 192.168.2.53 --- 0x4
  Dirección de Internet          Dirección física      Tipo
  192.168.2.1           44-4f-52-ed-c3-c8     estático  
  192.168.2.92          86-34-64-7d-dc-ee     estático
```

Se que esto quizás se pueda resolver con **regex**, pero observando el comportamiento del archivo de salida creo que no es necesario.

- Si una línea **no empieza con espacio** quiere decir que es una interface, y la dirección IP está en la segunda palabra.
- De lo contrario, la primera palabra posiblemente es una IP y la segunda es una MAC. Pero la siguiente línea después de la interface es un texto descriptivo, entonces para descartarla, se verifica si la primera palabra, quitando los puntos, está compuesta de números (o sea, si es una IP).

```
data = {}

with open('temp.txt', 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        info = line.split()
        if not info: # si es una linea en blanco
            continue
        if not line.startswith(' '):
            parent = info[1]
            data[parent] = []
        elif (info[0].replace('.', '')).isnumeric():
            data[parent].append([info[0], info[1]])

print(data)
```

Lo cual produce un diccionario que puedes utilizar para trabajar posteriormente en JSON, servir en API, etc. Claro, es un ejemplo de salida, ya que no lo especificaste, pero lo importante es parsear el archivo, así que a partir de ahí te puede servir para construir tu propio formato.

```
{
    '10.0.1.128': [
        ['10.0.1.1', '70-a8-57-ed-c3-c8'], 
        ['10.0.1.102', '40-6d-64-f7-dc-ee'], 
        ['10.0.1.147', '80-68-95-77-06-07']
    ], 
    '192.168.2.53': [
        ['192.168.2.1', '44-4f-52-ed-c3-c8'], 
        ['192.168.2.92', '86-34-64-7d-dc-ee']
    ]
}
```

Comment: increíble muchas gracias se nota que todavía me falta mucho

Answer (score 1):

Una solución:

```
import subprocess

def main():
    for linea in subprocess.Popen("arp -an", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout:
        partes = linea.decode().split()
        print(partes[1][1:-1], partes[3])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Nos evitamos el uso de archivos intermedios ejecutando el comando con `Popen`, lo cual nos permite recuperar la salida estandar directamente.

Las líneas devueltas por `Popen` son del estilo:

```
jaime@gear:~/PycharmProjects/pandas$ arp -an
? (192.168.0.1) at 00:26:9e:17:b2:20 [ether] on enp3s0
? (192.168.0.254) at c8:be:19:8c:38:42 [ether] on enp3s0
```

De cada línea tomamos el segundo y cuarto elemento (luego de hacer `split()`).

produce:

```
192.168.0.1 00:26:9e:17:b2:20
192.168.0.254 c8:be:19:8c:38:42

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: tambien me podria ser util en el futuro